# How to create Rectangle object required by add method of the artboards object in Illustrator CS5.1+?

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to add new artboard with the help of java script. I wasn't able to find solution nowhere. The scripting guidelines from adobe are just poor (to not use more strong words).

What ever I'm trying it returns the error:

> Error 1242: Illegal argument - argument 1 - Rectangle value expected

when I use value of `artboard.artboardRect` from other artboard then it creates artboard in the same place but I can't modify it (resize) which makes this option useless.

```
artboards.add(artboards[0].artboardRect);//works
artboards.add([0,0,200,50]);//Error 1200: an Illustrator error coccurred: 1346458189('PARAM')
var rect = artboards[0].artboardRect;
rect[0] = 0;
rect[1] = 0;
rect[2] = 200;
rect[3] = 50;
artboards.add(rect);//Error 1242: Illegal argument - argument 1 - Rectangle value expected
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After searching extensively I've found this workaround:

```
var newRect = function(x, y, width, height) {
    var l = 0;
    var t = 1;
    var r = 2;
    var b = 3;

    var rect = [];

    rect[l] = x;
    rect[t] = -y;
    rect[r] = width + x;
    rect[b] = -(height - rect[t]);

    return rect;
};

artboard = artboards.add(artboards[0].artboardRect);
artboard.name = "new name";
artboard.artboardRect = newRect(0, 0, 200, 50);
```

Comment: Adobe's documentation is crap. This should be a native method. Thank you for providing this.

Comment: An array will work, it just has to follow certain rules which Vlad's answer describes. The array follows the format of `[left, top, right, bottom]`. `right` must be positive, and `bottom` must be negative.

Answer (score 4):

In several places in [Illustrator Scripting PDFs](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/illustrator/scripting.html) `rect` or `someOtherPropRect` is defined as "array of 4 numbers". For example,

```
var document = app.documents.add();
$.writeln(document.artboards[0].artboardRect); // 0,792,612,0
```

returned values corresponds to `topLeftX, topLeftY, bottomRightX, bottomRightY`.

To make sense of these values, we need to take a look at the coordiate system of Illustrator. Illustrator's UI uses a [modified coordinate system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbOML.jpg), not the actual [cartesian one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvbV1.jpg). In other words, top left of the screen is the origin, not bottom left. But when scripting, actual cartesian coordinate system is used.

Because of this difference in coordinate system, entered values that are on the `Y` axis should be nagative. So, if I want to reposition and resize the artboard, say, move it to `(200,50)` and resize it to `(400,300)`, what I need to do is:

```
var document = app.activeDocument;
var artboard = document.artboards[0];

var x = 200;
var y = 50;
var w = 400;
var h = 300;

artboard.artboardRect = [x, -y, (x + w), -(y + h)];

$.writeln(document.artboards[0].artboardRect); // 200, -50, 600, -350
```

This solution can be wrapped in a function:

```
function rect(x, y, w, h) {
    return [x, -y, (x + w), -(y + h)];
}

artboard.artboardRect = rect(200, 50, 400, 300);
```

Both `Y` and `H` should be negative, otherwise you'll get an error saying

> Error 1200: an Illustrator error occurred: 1346458189 ('PARM')

or incorrect reposition/resize.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case someone else encounters `Error: an Illustrator error occurred: 1346458189 ('PARM')`.

In CS6 at least this happens if `height` **is not** negative or if `width` **is** negative. This applies to all values of type `rect`.

`x` and `y` can be positive or negative, it does't matter.

so this **will** work:

```
app.activeDocument.artboards.add([0 , 0, 200, -50]);
app.activeDocument.artboards.add([-10 , -10, 200, -50]);
app.activeDocument.artboards.add([10 , 10, 200, -50]);
```

but this **will not** work:

```
app.activeDocument.artboards.add([0 , 0, 200, 50])
app.activeDocument.artboards.add([0 , 0, -200, -50])
app.activeDocument.artboards.add([0 , 0, -200, 50])
```